# What is the python equivalent for 'javap' in java?

Tags: python

How can I see class methods via the command line for Python definitions?

In java, if I want to see the all methods of the `Scanner` class, then I can do it by this way:

```
javap *full_class_name*
```

Example:

```
 user@hostname:~$ javap java.util.Scanner
    Compiled from "Scanner.java"
    public final class java.util.Scanner implements java.util.Iterator<java.lang.String>, java.io.Closeable {
      static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;
      public java.util.Scanner(java.lang.Readable);
      // etc. ...
    }
```

I want to see all the methods of a class in python, how can I do it? I want to be able to look up what methods are available when coding; I'm a beginner and don't want to have to search the internet each time.

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat: the reason people ask is because if you needed those names *programmatically* then my answer would have been different.

Comment: (When you have a practicable method to get information programmatically, it should be obvious how to roll your own command line tool. Most IDEs support accessing what API doc is available, if in the context of *auto completion*. Make [providing such information for code you write](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) a habit.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`pydoc` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pydoc.html) to get help on Python objects, including the methods:

```
$ python -m pydoc str
Help on class str in module builtins:

class str(object)
 |  str(object='') -> str
 |  str(bytes_or_buffer[, encoding[, errors]]) -> str
 |
 |  Create a new string object from the given object. If encoding or
 |  errors is specified, then the object must expose a data buffer
 |  that will be decoded using the given encoding and error handler.
 |  Otherwise, returns the result of object.__str__() (if defined)
 |  or repr(object).
 |  encoding defaults to sys.getdefaultencoding().
 |  errors defaults to 'strict'.
 |
 |  Methods defined here:
 |
 |  __add__(self, value, /)
 |      Return self+value.
 |
 |  __contains__(self, key, /)
 |      Return key in self.
# .... etc.
```

If you already have a Python interpreter open, you can use the built-in [`help()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) to access the same information.

Comment: Thank you , i don't know why everyone is downvoting this question ?

Comment: @SanjayPrajapat: I can't read minds, sorry. I suggest you read [ask] carefully, follow the advice given and in future share your research in the question.